# Print TAB in JSTL

Tags: jstl, output, cout, display

I have a simple question:

What's the equivalent of the following C statement in JSTL?

```
    printf("\tHello");
```

I want to be able to include a TAB in the output. I know I can do:

```
<c:out value="Hello"/>
```

but that would not include a TAB before the word Hello. I tried &emsp as well, but with no success.

Comment: Just have a tab directly in the HTML source code. But of course, this won't be displayed differently than a single space by the browser, unless you're in a <pre> block or equivalent. What exactly have you tried, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead. Your posted code doesn't have any tab.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
  zzzz<c:out value="&emsp;Hello" escapeXml="false"/>zzzzz
```

and so does just

```
zzzz${"&emsp;hellllo"}zzzz
```